# Getting barplot instead of scatterplot in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to `plot` from a dataframe (`df`) that has the following first 8 rows:

```
df = 

V1  V2  V3
1   34.62365962451697   78.0246928153624    0
2   30.28671076822607   43.89499752400101   0
3   35.84740876993872   72.90219802708364   0
4   60.18259938620976   86.30855209546826   1
5   79.0327360507101    75.3443764369103    1
6   45.08327747668339   56.3163717815305    0
7   61.10666453684766   96.51142588489624   1
8   75.02474556738889   46.55401354116538   1
```

I'm using `plot(df$V1, df$V2)` but what I get is this image:
[image: R-plot]

When I use `plot(df)` instead it shows me the right results shown below in a red square.

[image: R-scatterplot]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your columns are factors. When you read in the data, add the option `colClasses = rep("numeric", 3)` or apply this to your current data.frame `df = data.frame(apply(df, 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))`